# How to set value of an unordered map to number other than 0

Tags: c++, unordered-map

When I declare an unordered map, then by default all the values are assigned to 0. But I want to assign all the values to say -1. Is there any way to do that?

For example see this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map> 

using namespace std;
 unordered_map<int, int> umap; 
 

int main()
{
     cout<<umap[10];
    
}
```

The output of this code is 0. See that an unassigned location is giving output as 0 by default. My question is, is there any way to change this and assign a number that I like?

Comment: Beware: `umap[10]` actually inserts into the map, if the element did not exist. Your cout line is **modifying** the map.

Comment: ^ what @spectras is saying is the whole issue. There are no "all values" in your example. As soon as you write `umap[10]` you create a value in the map. As you don't assign is a value, the default constructor is used. If you would write something like `cout<<umap[10]=-1;` this would be different.

Comment: When accessing `umap[10]` and no instance was found then a default (value-)constructed element is put in. So for `unordered_map<int,int>` it will always be `0`. You can replace `int` with a class compatible with `int` that default constructors to `-1` but unsure if that's wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom type with a default constructor to initialize to `-1`:

```cpp
struct MyInt
{
    int i = -1;
};

unordered_map<int, MyInt> umap;
```

You can provide `operator int()` and other operators to mimic the behavior of a regular `int` if you don't want to type the `.i` accessor.